# Trying to find an android data structure

Tags: android, data-structures, dictionary, queue

I am trying to implement a data structure which allows me to keep track of an index (so I can blindly access the data points), a key (which needs to be there to identify the data in the rest of the program), and a value.

I've looked at a map, but that does not allow me to access the data points without any key. I need some combination of a Queue and a Map. Does this exist and I'm just missing it? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is a LinkedHashMap.  It will return an ordered collection and you can access values via a key.

```
LinkedHashMap<Key, Value> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<Key, Value>();

myMap.put(aKey, aValue); //adds to map.
myMap.values(); //returns collection of values
aValue = myMap.get(Key); //returns a value with the given key
```

Comment: It seems that the constructor can include an initial size as well as if it is sorted by which one was accessed most recently.
How can I make it remove whichever one is the eldest? I'm particularly looking at making this method execute.
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry(java.util.Map.Entry<K, V>)

Does it do it automatically if the capacity is reached?

Comment: LinkedHashMap actually has an underlying linked list and Map. The collection it returns can be iterated starting from the front. I believe there are only two ways you can remove the last node.  Iterate the list to the end or remove it using the key.  So maybe the LinkedHashMap is not what you are looking for.  You may need to write your own data structure by combining an ArrayQueue and a Map.